# scroll bar showing on other content

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicescroll

I'm working on a tab menu, so I have 2 contents that displays a table with [scrollbar](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll). my problem is when I switch to the other content the scroll from the other content retains.

hope you help me thanks.

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/yEGgQo)

```
$('tbody').niceScroll({autohidemode: false});
$('.table:first-child').show();
$('.side ul li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;

  $('.container .table:nth-child('+ index +')').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering a `resize` on the nicescroll object seems to work:

```
$('tbody').niceScroll({autohidemode: false});
$('.table:first-child').show();
$('.side ul li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;

  $('.container .table:nth-child('+ index +')').show().siblings().hide();

  $('tbody').getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

[Example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzejRO)

Comment: No problemo. :)